# On hover swap images

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 dropdowns namely NEW & SHOP

when I hover over the New Menu 1, it should show the related image and same when I hover over New Menu 2 it should show the related image in a div which has a class ".menu-viewer".

Right now this works, but it changes the image of the shop menu also.

Also, the default image for the shop is not shown by default.

Please refer the Fiddle I have created and tell me what am I doing wrong.

I hope I have explained my problem clearly. As it sounds a little confusing, please feel free to ask me.

**https://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/qwtono6c/**

```
 var $img = $('.menu-viewer  img'),
 dsrc = $img.attr('src');
 $('.menu-list ul li a').hover(function() {
 var $this = $(this).addClass('hover');
  $img.attr('src', $this.data('image'));
 }, function() {
 $(this).removeClass('hover');
$img.attr('src', dsrc);
 });


 $('.menu-list ul li').bind('mouseenter focusin',function() {
 $($(this).attr('href')).show();
 }).bind('mouseleave focusout',function() {
 $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
 });
```

Comment: Do you have a image of what you are trying to do? There is a lot of nesting going on here maybe without it being necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the image within the current block.  In the following I have used jQuery closest to get the closest ancestor megamenu and changed the image based on that:

```js
$('.menu-list ul li a').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this).addClass('hover'),
    $img = $this.closest('.megamenu').find('.menu-viewer  img');
    
  $this.data('original', $img.attr('src'));
  $img.attr('src', $this.data('image'));
}, function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $img = $this.closest('.megamenu').find('.menu-viewer  img');
  
  $this.removeClass('hover');
  $img.attr('src', $this.data('original'));
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">NEW MENU</a>
  <div class="megamenu clearfix">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x align-center align-middle">
        <div class="cell small-8 shrink">
          <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell small-4">
              <div class="menu-list">
                <ul>
                  <li id="menulist1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1">NEW MENU 1</a></li>
                  <li id="menulist2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2">NEW MENU 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell small-8">
              <div class="menu-viewer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1" alt="Cruise Collection" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Shop</a>
  <div class="megamenu clearfix">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x align-center align-middle">
        <div class="cell small-8 shrink">
          <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell small-2">
              <div class="menu-list">
                <ul>
                  <li id="menulist3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 1">SHOP 1</a></li>
                  <li id="menulist4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 2">SHOP 2</a></li>
                  <li id="menulist5"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 3">SHOP 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell small-8">
              <div class="menu-viewer">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP1" alt="Cruise Collection">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Edit as per comments

```js
$('.menu-list ul li a').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this).addClass('hover'),
    $images = $this.closest('.megamenu').find('.menu-viewer  img');

  $images.eq(0).addClass('hidden');
  $images.eq(1).attr('src', $this.data('image')).removeClass('hidden');

}, function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $images = $this.closest('.megamenu').find('.menu-viewer  img');
    
  $images.eq(1).addClass('hidden');
  $images.eq(0).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

.menu-viewer {
  position: relative;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">NEW MENU</a>
  <div class="megamenu clearfix">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x align-center align-middle">
        <div class="cell small-8 shrink">
          <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell small-4">
              <div class="menu-list">
                <ul>
                  <li id="menulist1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1">NEW MENU 1</a></li>
                  <li id="menulist2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2">NEW MENU 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell small-8">
              <div class="menu-viewer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1" alt="Cruise Collection" />
                <img class="hidden" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1" alt="Cruise Collection" /></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Shop</a>
  <div class="megamenu clearfix">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x align-center align-middle">
        <div class="cell small-8 shrink">
          <div class="grid-x">
            <div class="cell small-2">
              <div class="menu-list">
                <ul>
                  <li id="menulist3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 1">SHOP 1</a></li>
                  <li id="menulist4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 2">SHOP 2</a></li>
                  <li id="menulist5"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 3">SHOP 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell small-8">
              <div class="menu-viewer">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP1" alt="Cruise Collection">
                <img class="hidden" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP1" alt="Cruise Collection">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Pete, you answer worked like a charm, now the only problem is how can i give it a fadein/fadeout. Thank you

Comment: If you want to fade one image in whilst another fades out then you will need 2 images, give me a minute

Comment: @San, above is a quick demo of how I would do it, it's a little buggy (eg not sure why first animation is not honouring the absolute positioning) but I'll let you sort that (or ask a new question)

Comment: Hi Pete, It works pretty erratic, I will try from my side if I can do, but thanks a ton for the effort...cheers

Comment: You may need to start with a second image rather than creating it and appending, let me have another go - I went out to lunch and was too busy stuffing my face!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168319/discussion-between-san-and-pete).

Comment: Hi Pete, any luck with the question? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete, you are a rockstar

Answer (score 0):

You could try reaching out for help with css, also included an `index` variable in case you add more images in the future. Notice this relies on every anchor having an id of the form `menulist + <number>`. Also I made it so that when you hover out of the link, the menu img does not switch back to the previous state, dunno if that goes against your desired behavior but it seemed more natural this way

Give it a go

```js
$('.menu-list ul li a').mouseenter(function() {
    var $this = $(this).addClass('hover');
    var index = $this.parent().attr('id').match(/menulist(.+)/)[1];
    
    $this.closest('.cell').siblings('.small-8:first').find('img:nth-child('+index+')').addClass('active').siblings('img').removeClass('active');
     
  });
```

```css
ul{list-style:none}

img.cruise-coll{
  display: none
}

img.cruise-coll.active{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">NEW MENU</a>
   <div class="megamenu clearfix">
      <div class="grid-container">
         <div class="grid-x align-center align-middle">
            <div class="cell small-8 shrink">
               <div class="grid-x">
                  <div class="cell small-4">
                     <div class="menu-list">
                        <ul>
                           <li id="menulist1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1">NEW MENU 1</a></li>
                           <li id="menulist2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2">NEW MENU 2</a></li>
                           <li id="menulist3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2">NEW MENU 3</a></li>
                           <li id="menulist4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2">NEW MENU 4</a></li>
                           <li id="menulist5"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2">NEW MENU 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cell small-8">
                     <div class="menu-viewer">
                     <img class="cruise-coll active" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 1" alt="Cruise Collection"/>
                     <img class="cruise-coll" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 2" alt="Cruise Collection"/>
                     <img class="cruise-coll" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 3" alt="Cruise Collection"/>
                     <img class="cruise-coll" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 4" alt="Cruise Collection"/>
                     <img class="cruise-coll" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=NEW MENU 5" alt="Cruise Collection"/></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">Shop</a>
   <div class="megamenu clearfix">
      <div class="grid-container">
         <div class="grid-x align-center align-middle">
            <div class="cell small-8 shrink">
               <div class="grid-x">
                  <div class="cell small-2">
                     <div class="menu-list">
                        <ul>
                           <li id="menulist3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 1">SHOP 1</a></li>
                           <li id="menulist4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 2">SHOP 2</a></li>
                           <li id="menulist5"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-image="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP 3">SHOP 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cell small-8">
                     <div class="menu-viewer">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=SHOP1" alt="Cruise Collection">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
</ul>
```